# Issue with overlapping text at column at report having predefined number of columns

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to display data column wise in jasper report to achieve the same i have created jasper report with A4 size and change the page property to 3 column vertically so it shows data vertically in 3 column.

The issue is if i have the one record then it shows correct data but if i have multiple data then it prints data on exiting data which i do not want is there any way we can force jasper to show data in parallel to each other in vertical manner instead of printing it on top of each other.

Below is the sample table which i have used for testing purpose with insert statements.

```
 create table jasper_demo(  
  no         number(2,0),  
  name       varchar2(14),  
  loc        varchar2(13)  
 )

 insert into jasper_demo values(10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');

 insert into jasper_demo values(20, 'INFLATION', 'LONDON');

 insert into jasper_demo values(30, 'GAMMA-RAYS', 'CHINA');

 insert into jasper_demo values(40, 'HEXA-RAYS', 'JAPAN');
```

Query to retrieve data from db(oracle 11g)

```
SELECT
b.no,b.name,b.loc
FROM
(SELECT LEVEL  as lvl from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24)
 a
full outer JOIN
(  SELECT    rownum  as lvl,
      no,
      name,
      loc
     from jasper_demo 
  )   b ON a.lvl = b.lvl
order by a.lvl
```

Source of jasper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_1" columnCount="3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="185" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c58759d6-4d76-455f-89bd-1a9b204e0bc8">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    b.no,b.name,b.loc
FROM
    (SELECT LEVEL  as lvl from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24)
     a
full outer JOIN
    (  SELECT    rownum  as lvl,
      no,
      name,
      loc
     from jasper_demo 
      )   b ON a.lvl = b.lvl
   order by a.lvl]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="NO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LOC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="NO">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="NAME">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="LOC">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{LOC}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="128" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="f8ac39df-75ca-44e6-aca6-eef38ff74f73">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="45" width="100" height="30" uuid="44c44cc6-c7d4-44c5-8907-af98439b2fc6">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="80" width="100" height="30" uuid="8186d204-5448-49d5-893d-6a953f21cdf8">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LOC}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="202" y="9" width="100" height="30" uuid="6fc3b438-b12d-4f43-b4b3-c040806f2ac1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="202" y="44" width="100" height="30" uuid="31af60e9-505b-438d-9eb3-4fc8d2c9bf4c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="202" y="79" width="100" height="30" uuid="48ffb03f-b785-42b6-b2b7-4fe087d3550e">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{NO}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LOC}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Problem i'm facing:

[image: This is the screen shot of wrong display]

Comment: Alex i think so both are very different the in a way if you check

Comment: Did you try to play with report's width?

Comment: Actually what i want is to display result parallel if i select isStretchWithOverflow then how does it make any impact on displaying result... AFAIK isStretchWithOverflow  is used to display data if data if overflwoing here in my situation there is no over flowing of data its adjustment of data so it display non-repeating value and also all the records in parallel

Comment: Try to decrease the report's width (width = sum of both textFields width)

Comment: AS i share in image above there is a fix columne layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of the report is wrong.

[image: Wrong design]

The right "column" with three textFields are out of region of your column.

You have set this properties for report:

- *columnCount="3"*
- *pageWidth="595"*
- *columnWidth="185"*

and the width the x-position of textFields from second (right) column is greater than *185*.

The fix is very simple. You should set sizes and positions for textFields that all elements will be at column.

### The sample of good design

#### Template

All elements are at region of report's column.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report with 3 columns" columnCount="3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="185" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c58759d6-4d76-455f-89bd-1a9b204e0bc8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="users.csv"/>
    <field name="category" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="user" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="128" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="90" height="30" uuid="f8ac39df-75ca-44e6-aca6-eef38ff74f73">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="45" width="90" height="30" uuid="44c44cc6-c7d4-44c5-8907-af98439b2fc6">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{user}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="80" width="90" height="30" uuid="8186d204-5448-49d5-893d-6a953f21cdf8">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="10" width="90" height="30" uuid="6fc3b438-b12d-4f43-b4b3-c040806f2ac1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="45" width="90" height="30" uuid="31af60e9-505b-438d-9eb3-4fc8d2c9bf4c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{user}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="80" width="90" height="30" uuid="48ffb03f-b785-42b6-b2b7-4fe087d3550e">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The design at *Jaspersoft Studio* looks like:

[image: Right design]

#### Datasource

I've used simple *csv* datasource:

```
category,user,status
1,user1,WORK
1,user1,HOLIDAY
1,user2,SICK
2,user1,WORK
2,user2,WORK
2,user2,HOLIDAY
2,user3,HOLIDAY
2,user4,SICK
3,user1,HOLIDAY
3,user3,HOLIDAY
3,user5,HOLIDAY
4,user1,WORK
4,user1,HOLIDAY
4,user2,SICK
4,user2,WORK
4,user2,SICK
4,user3,HOLIDAY
4,user4,HOLIDAY
4,user5,HOLIDAY
```

#### Output result

The output result is 3 columns per row (one column with two textFields) - 6 columns of textFields per pseudo row.

[image: Output result at JSS]

The overlapping effect is gone.